# (Ubuntu) When I run "rails server" it runs, but then exits and gives me a bunch of what I presume are error messages

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu, ubuntu-12.04

I am fairly new to Ubuntu and Programming and working with terminals and after searching for quite a while I couldn't find any information on my problem or I couldn't think of what to search exactly and so I thought posting my own question would help because most of the errors that I saw other people having were much shorter and were different even though they both started out the same way with the rails server running for a second or two and then exiting, then outputting errors. Any help of appreciated.

**Code that I ran:**

```
root@KyleBuntu:~/Desktop/Rails/first_app# rails server
>=> Booting WEBrick
>=> Rails 4.0.8 application starting in development on http://0.0.0.0:3000
>=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
>=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
>Exiting
>/home/verendus/Desktop/Rails/first_app/config/environments/development.rb:1:in `<top (required)>': undefined method `configure' for #<FirstApp::Application:0x00000002e01dc8> (NoMethodError)
>   from /home/verendus/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/activesupport-4.0.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:229:in `require'
>   from /home/verendus/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/activesupport-4.0.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:229:in `block in require'
>   from /home/verendus/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/activesupport-4.0.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:214:in `load_dependency'
>   from /home/verendus/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/activesupport-4.0.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:229:in `require'
>   from /home/verendus/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/railties-4.0.8/lib/rails/engine.rb:591:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Engine>'
>   from /home/verendus/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/railties-4.0.8/lib/rails/engine.rb:590:in `each'
>   from /home/verendus/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/railties-4.0.8/lib/rails/engine.rb:590:in `block in <class:Engine>'
>   from /home/verendus/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/railties-4.0.8/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
>   from /home/verendus/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/railties-4.0.8/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
>   from /home/verendus/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/railties-4.0.8/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
>   from /home/verendus/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p481/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:150:in `block in tsort_each'
>   from /home/verendus/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p481/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:183:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
>   from /home/verendus/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p481/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:210:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component_from'
>   from /home/verendus/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p481/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:219:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
>   from /home/verendus/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p481/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:209:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component_from'
>   from /home/verendus/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/railties-4.0.8/lib/rails/initializable.rb:44:in `each'
>   from /home/verendus/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/railties-4.0.8/lib/rails/initializable.rb:44:in `tsort_each_child'
>   from /home/verendus/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p481/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:203:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
>   from /home/verendus/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p481/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:182:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
>   from /home/verendus/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p481/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:180:in `each'
>   from /home/verendus/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p481/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:180:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
>   from /home/verendus/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p481/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:148:in `tsort_each'
>   from /home/verendus/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/railties-4.0.8/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
>   from /home/verendus/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/railties-4.0.8/lib/rails/application.rb:215:in `initialize!'
>   from /home/verendus/Desktop/Rails/first_app/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
>   from /home/verendus/Desktop/Rails/first_app/config.ru:3:in `require'
>   from /home/verendus/Desktop/Rails/first_app/config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
>   from /home/verendus/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `instance_eval'
>   from /home/verendus/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `initialize'
>   from /home/verendus/Desktop/Rails/first_app/config.ru:in `new'
>   from /home/verendus/Desktop/Rails/first_app/config.ru:in `<main>'
>   from /home/verendus/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `eval'
>   from /home/verendus/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `new_from_string'
>   from /home/verendus/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `parse_file'
>   from /home/verendus/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/server.rb:277:in `build_app_and_options_from_config'
>   from /home/verendus/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/server.rb:199:in `app'
>   from /home/verendus/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/railties-4.0.8/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:48:in `app'
>   from /home/verendus/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/server.rb:314:in `wrapped_app'
>   from /home/verendus/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/railties-4.0.8/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:75:in `start'
>   from /home/verendus/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/railties-4.0.8/lib/rails/commands.rb:76:in `block in <top (required)>'
>   from /home/verendus/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/railties-4.0.8/lib/rails/commands.rb:71:in `tap'
>   from /home/verendus/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/railties-4.0.8/lib/rails/commands.rb:71:in `<top (required)>'
>   from bin/rails:8:in `require'
>   from bin/rails:8:in `<main>'
```

If any information is needed then I can provide it. I am new to both Ubuntu and Programming so sorry if I have made some simple mistakes somewhere. Any help is much appreciated.

**Config as per request:**

```
Rails.application.configure do
  # Settings specified here will take precedence over those in config/application.rb.

  # In the development environment your application's code is reloaded on
  # every request. This slows down response time but is perfect for development
  # since you don't have to restart the web server when you make code changes.
  config.cache_classes = false

  # Do not eager load code on boot.
  config.eager_load = false

  # Show full error reports and disable caching.
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = true
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = false

  # Don't care if the mailer can't send.
  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false

  # Print deprecation notices to the Rails logger.
  config.active_support.deprecation = :log

  # Raise an error on page load if there are pending migrations.
  config.active_record.migration_error = :page_load

  # Debug mode disables concatenation and preprocessing of assets.
  # This option may cause significant delays in view rendering with a large
  # number of complex assets.
  config.assets.debug = true

  # Adds additional error checking when serving assets at runtime.
  # Checks for improperly declared sprockets dependencies.
  # Raises helpful error messages.
  config.assets.raise_runtime_errors = true

  # Raises error for missing translations
  # config.action_view.raise_on_missing_translations = true
end
```

**2nd try:**

```
=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 4.0.8 application starting in development on http://0.0.0.0:3000
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
Exiting
/home/verendus/Desktop/Rails/first_app/config/environments/development.rb:1:in `<top (required)>': undefined method `application' for FirstApp:Module (NoMethodError)
    from /home/verendus/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/activesupport-4.0.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:229:in `require'
    from /home/verendus/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/activesupport-4.0.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:229:in `block in require'
    from /home/verendus/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/activesupport-4.0.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:214:in `load_dependency'
    from /home/verendus/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/activesupport-4.0.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:229:in `require'
    from /home/verendus/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/railties-4.0.8/lib/rails/engine.rb:591:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Engine>'
    from /home/verendus/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/railties-4.0.8/lib/rails/engine.rb:590:in `each'
    from /home/verendus/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/railties-4.0.8/lib/rails/engine.rb:590:in `block in <class:Engine>'
    from /home/verendus/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/railties-4.0.8/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
    from /home/verendus/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/railties-4.0.8/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
    from /home/verendus/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/railties-4.0.8/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
    from /home/verendus/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p481/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:150:in `block in tsort_each'
    from /home/verendus/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p481/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:183:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
    from /home/verendus/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p481/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:210:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component_from'
    from /home/verendus/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p481/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:219:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
    from /home/verendus/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p481/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:209:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component_from'
    from /home/verendus/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/railties-4.0.8/lib/rails/initializable.rb:44:in `each'
    from /home/verendus/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/railties-4.0.8/lib/rails/initializable.rb:44:in `tsort_each_child'
    from /home/verendus/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p481/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:203:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
    from /home/verendus/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p481/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:182:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
    from /home/verendus/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p481/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:180:in `each'
    from /home/verendus/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p481/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:180:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
    from /home/verendus/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p481/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:148:in `tsort_each'
    from /home/verendus/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/railties-4.0.8/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
    from /home/verendus/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/railties-4.0.8/lib/rails/application.rb:215:in `initialize!'
    from /home/verendus/Desktop/Rails/first_app/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/verendus/Desktop/Rails/first_app/config.ru:3:in `require'
    from /home/verendus/Desktop/Rails/first_app/config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
    from /home/verendus/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `instance_eval'
    from /home/verendus/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `initialize'
    from /home/verendus/Desktop/Rails/first_app/config.ru:in `new'
    from /home/verendus/Desktop/Rails/first_app/config.ru:in `<main>'
    from /home/verendus/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `eval'
    from /home/verendus/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `new_from_string'
    from /home/verendus/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `parse_file'
    from /home/verendus/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/server.rb:277:in `build_app_and_options_from_config'
    from /home/verendus/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/server.rb:199:in `app'
    from /home/verendus/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/railties-4.0.8/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:48:in `app'
    from /home/verendus/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/server.rb:314:in `wrapped_app'
    from /home/verendus/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/railties-4.0.8/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:75:in `start'
    from /home/verendus/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/railties-4.0.8/lib/rails/commands.rb:76:in `block in <top (required)>'
    from /home/verendus/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/railties-4.0.8/lib/rails/commands.rb:71:in `tap'
    from /home/verendus/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/railties-4.0.8/lib/rails/commands.rb:71:in `<top (required)>'
    from bin/rails:8:in `require'
    from bin/rails:8:in `<main>'
```

Comment: Can you post your config/environments/development.rb code?

Comment: @Icicle added what I presume you wanted to the bottom of the post.

Comment: Change Rails.application.configure to FirstApp.application.configure

Comment: @Icicle I'm afraid that hasn't fixed it yet.

Comment: Are you still getting same error?

Comment: Also check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22977051/error-launching-rails-server-undefined-method-configure

Comment: @Icicle I think it's a smaller amount of errors, but I am not completely sure. (I'll add it to the post)

Comment: @Icicle I am using a modified Gemfile which might be the source of my problems, but I modified it because I am following the instructions in [this](http://www.railstutorial.org/book/beginning#sec-bundler)

Comment: If it is sample application then can you push your code into Github?

Comment: @Icicle I sorry I don't understand what that means. What exactly should I do?

Comment: Please create new account on https://github.com/ and push your code for review. Post your Github repository link here.

Comment: https://github.com/dasd190/Ruby-on-Rails-Help @Icicle I want to add my config file and gemfile, but I'm afraid I don't know how to.

Comment: Hey .. can you refer this tutorial and push your code http://guides.railsgirls.com/github/

Comment: @Icicle Will do that when I wake up, it's 2:30 am here

Comment: @ Icicle I have pushed my file to GitHub

Comment: @ Verendus Have posted separate answer with all details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please change following line in your application config/envrironments/development.rb file

From

```
FirstApp.application.configure
```

To

```
FirstApp::Application.configure
```

I also noticed that you have not added secret token yet.

Please run following command to generate secret token

```
rake secret
```

You need to copy secret token in new file in config/initializers/secret_token.rb

```
FirstApp::Application.config.secret_key_base = '<secret token generated>'
```

Your application will be up and running after that :)

Comment: I believe that I did it correctly, but I am not sure. I changed the dev file to say FirstApp::Application.configure, and I created a new file in that secret token directory with a file that says that thing above, but I am not sure if that is what you wanted. I updated the github.

Comment: Are you still facing issue when you start your application?

Comment: Still getting a load of errors when I try 'rails server'

Comment: You removed do in development.rb file ... it should be FirstApp::Application.configure do ..

Comment: Thank god, that fixed it. I thank you so very much, also is the @ working or do you get a notification anyway?

Comment: Can you please accept answer so that question can be closed.

Answer (score 1):

You just need your first line to say:

```
FirstApp.application.configure do
```