# bundle exec rspec spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

Hi Everyone i am working on Hart's book just like most people and came across tis error in Chapter 3. Every time i try to type: `bundle exec rspec spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb` i receive the below error:

```
/home/action/rails_projects/sample_app/config/environments/test.rb
:1:in `<top (required)>': undefined method `configure' for #<Sampl
eApp::Application:0x007fc2f39dcac0> (NoMethodError)               
from /home/action/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.8
/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:229:in `require'              
    from /home/action/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.8
/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:229:in `block in require'     
    from /home/action/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.8
/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:214:in `load_dependency'      
    from /home/action/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.8
/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:229:in `require'              
    from /home/action/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.8/lib/
rails/engine.rb:591:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Engine>'       
    from /home/action/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.8/lib/
rails/engine.rb:590:in `each'                                     
    from /home/action/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.8/lib/
rails/engine.rb:590:in `block in <class:Engine>'                  
    from /home/action/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.8/lib/
rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'                      
    from /home/action/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.8/lib/
rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
```

My initial test.rb file is below however i am still getting the error

```
Rails.application.configure do
# Settings specified here will take precedence over those in config/application.rb.
# The test environment is used exclusively to run your application's
# test suite. You never need to work with it otherwise. Remember that
# your test database is "scratch space" for the test suite and is wiped
# and recreated between test runs. Don't rely on the data there!
config.cache_classes = true
# Do not eager load code on boot. This avoids loading your whole application
# just for the purpose of running a single test. If you are using a tool that
# preloads Rails for running tests, you may have to set it to true.
config.eager_load = false
# Configure static asset server for tests with Cache-Control for performance.
config.serve_static_assets  = true
config.static_cache_control = 'public, max-age=3600'
# Show full error reports and disable caching.
config.consider_all_requests_local       = true
config.action_controller.perform_caching = false
# Raise exceptions instead of rendering exception templates.
config.action_dispatch.show_exceptions = false
# Disable request forgery protection in test environment.
config.action_controller.allow_forgery_protection = false
# Tell Action Mailer not to deliver emails to the real world.
# The :test delivery method accumulates sent emails in the
# ActionMailer::Base.deliveries array.
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :test
# Print deprecation notices to the stderr.
config.active_support.deprecation = :stderr
# Raises error for missing translations
# config.action_view.raise_on_missing_translations = true
end
```

If anyone can help that would be great!

Comment: Show us your environment/test.rb, that's where the error is.

Comment: I posted the test.rb which is my environment/test.rb. sorry for confusion

Comment: I originally changed my test.rb code which gave me a different error so i changed it back to the original code and am getting this error now.

Comment: What version or Rails are you using. Are the first lines of `development.rb` and `production.rb` the same? They should be identical

Comment: possible duplicate of [Error launching Rails server: undefined method 'configure'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22977051/error-launching-rails-server-undefined-method-configure)

Comment: i am using Rails 4.0.8.. in development.rb it says SampleApp::Application configure do and in production.rb it says Rails.application.configure do ....i tried to change both to the same and the same error came up. Maybe i am missing something but do I need to define 'configure' in my test.rb file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I change the first line of development.rb production.rb and test.rb to SampleApp::Application.configure do fix this problem